# DLLImport is showing my current directory in another user machine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pinvoke, dllimport

I am new to PInvoke, I wanted to update my system volume using C#, I got one C++ dll and I have to just Import that DLL and use the methods to update the volume.

In C# I have written :

```
 public const String DllName = "ChangeVolumeWindows.dll";
 [DllImport(DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern void SetSystemVolume(double newVolume, VolumeUnit vUnit);
```

I have put my dll into the exe path.
It is working fine for my pc , but when I package the app and send it to another machine I getting error " DLL not found "
I have observed that DLLImport is looking for path of my pc, which is not correct
For example:
I have put my dll in C:/User/ABC/Source/App/bin/debug/ChangeVolumeWindows.dll
in some another machine also it is looking for the same path instead of taking dll from C:/User/AnotherMachineUser/Source/App/bin/debug/ChangeVolumeWindows.dll

Can some one suggest where my code is going wrong.

I have tried to put my dll inside the project and the rebuild. Still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: "*I have observed that DLLImport is looking for path of my pc, which is not correct*" -- how exactly did you observe this?

Comment: by checking the logs from another machine, I have used the try catch exception , in that

Comment: What exactly are you logging, and when?

Comment: I am logging in a method where setVolume is needed , in that it fails for another system mentioning cannot find the DLL in path of my code

Comment: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'ChangeVolumeWindows.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
at SetSystemVolume(Double newVolume, VolumeUnit vUnit)  in C:\Users\ABC\source\ s:line 217

Comment: That's not saying where it's trying to load the DLL from. That's the path to the source file where the exception occurred, and those paths are baked in at compile-time

Comment: I think you got confused by misinterpreting the file path in the exception message. I think it's most likely that this is the normal reason why native DLLs can't be loaded, and that's bitness: make sure that you configure your .NET application to run as the same bitness as your DLL. So if your DLL is 32-bit, make sure to configure your .NET application to run as x86, rather than "Any CPU"

Comment: @canton7 , i have build the dll in release/x64 and my application is having the same configuration

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath("\folders\ChangeVolumeWindows.dll")
```

Comment: I have tried but not working in my case